# get lowercase letters in c++ using getasynckeystate

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to get lowercase letters when i write to a file using `getasynckeystate` but i am unable to do so, i can not write symbols such as `@` and `$` either, this is the code i am using. I have tried using `GetKeyState` but that isn't working either, neither is `WM_KEYDOWN`.

```
if( GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767 )
{
    save(i, "keys.txt");
}
```

it is saving everything in uppercase letters, and no symbol is being saved when i try to use shift + any number key.

Comment: Same question as [C++ and GetAsyncKeyState() function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193185/c-and-getasynckeystate-function). Note that GetAsyncKeyState is intended only for very specific circumstances. Few programs should have any need for it. (In particular, you will have trouble using GetAsyncKeyState for typing on any non-English keyboard.)

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState()` will tell you whether a particular key is pressed or depressed at a certain point in time. A key being pressed is only part of the information required to post a character message (`WM_CHAR`) to a thread. If you want to record character input, handle `WM_CHAR` messages. If you just want to know who your GF is chatting with while you are not there, go download a keylogger.

Answer (score 1):

`GetAsyncKeyState()` works with more-or-less physical keystrokes. It can't tell you the difference between upper and lower case because it's still the same key (i.e. "a" and "A" are the same key on your keyboard). To determine case, it would need to take shift and caps-lock into account, along with keyboard layout and localisation. A similar issue affects several symbols, such as @ and and $. They vary too much between layouts and locales.

To get case information and other locale-specific stuff, you'll need to use `WM_CHAR` in conjunction with `TranslateMessage()`. You'll still need `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` for non-character keys though, such as Delete and F1-12. You can get more information from MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268(v=vs.85).aspx

As a side note, you're technically checking the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState()` incorrectly. Simply comparing the result to -32767 may not be reliable. From the documentation about the return value:

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState. However, you should not rely on this last behavior;