# Determine if a key should be capitalized using both shift and caps lock

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I'm wanting to determine if a letter should be uppercase or lowercase based on the state of the shift key and Caps-Lock. For example: if both are off or both are on, then the letter is lowercase. But if shift is pressed, and Caps-Lock is off, or if shift is not pressed, and Caps-Lock is on, then the letter should be uppercase.

I've tried simply looking at the high-order bit from `GetKeyState()` for the shift key to determine if it is pressed or not, and the low-order bit from `GetKeyState()` for determining if Caps-Lock is toggled, but it hasn't worked perfectly. Right now I'm just outputting the data to a text file to see what values I get. I got information from `GetKeyState()` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate)

Here's the function I'm using to determine what the case of a letter should be:

```
bool Capitalize(short int shift, short int caps){
    bool s = shift<0;
    bool c = (caps&1)!=0;
    return s!=c;
}
```

And here's where I'm calling the function:

```
ofstream write("test.txt", ios::app);
void main(){
    char c;
    for(;;){
        for(c=1;c<=222;c++){
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(c)==-32767){
                short int shift = GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
                short int caps = GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL);
                switch(c){
                    case 65:{
                        if(Capitalize(shift,caps))
                            write<<"A";
                        else
                            write<<"a";
                    }break;
                }
                write<<"\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I had Caps-Lock off, and was not holding down the shift key, the output was as follows:

```
A
a
a
a
```

Which if you notice, the first letter is uppercase, which I expected to be lowercase.
The same thing happened when I held down shift while Caps-Lock is on, which should produce lowercase letters. If either shift is held down, or Caps-Lock is on, but not both, then it seems to work fine and all letters are output as uppercase "A".
I'm not entirely sure as to why this is happening, but any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This answer seems promising. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193185/c-and-getasynckeystate-function

Comment: @ConnorJ.Toth i changed the definition of `s` and `c` in my first snippet to: `bool s = (shift&0x8000)!=0;` and `bool c = (caps&0x0001)!=0;` and this time, the first three letters are in the correct case, and the 4th letter is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me with the output you were expecting:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool Capitalize(short int shift, short int caps)
{
    bool s = shift < 0;
    bool c = (caps & 1) != 0;
    return s != c;
}

void main()
{
    unsigned char c;

    while (true)
    {
        for (c = 1; c <= 222; c++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(c) &1)
            {
                short int shift = GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
                short int caps = GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL);

                switch (c) 
                {
                    case 65: 
                    {
                        if (Capitalize(shift, caps))
                        {
                            std::cout << "A\n";
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            std::cout << "a\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```